# KMM template project of Android Studio does not create a runnable project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

When I create a new multiplatform project using the **KMM Application template** in Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
The Gradle wrapper is required to run the build from Xcode.

Please run the same command with `-Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.generate.wrapper=true` or run the `:wrapper` task to generate the wrapper manually.

See details about the wrapper at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html
```

The project can not be run, it has no configuration available:

[image]

I am using Android Studio latest version: **Android Studio - Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2** on macOS.

The version of gradle installed is **7.0**

[image]

Android Studio also displays the following warning:

[image]

Clicking on `Load Gradle Project` brings to the same error:

[image]

The `gradle-wrapper.properties` file uses **gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip**. (there is no [distribution version](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) `gradle-7.0-bin.zip` available)

When I try to create a `gradlew` file I get the following error:

[image]

I do not know to which command I can pass the option
`-Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.generate.wrapper=true`.

Changing the version of gradle in `gradle-wrapper.properties` as suggested brings to the following error after synchronizing the project:

[image]

I have never had any problem when using the KMM Application template of Android Studio.

Did someone have any idea what is happening and what I can do ?

Comment: I've had the same problem today. Fixed with `brew upgrade gradle`. Then, with Gradle 7.2, thee project worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Artyom Degtyarev, but it did not work for me. I have now gradle 7.2 installed, and AS always complains about "The Gradle wrapper is required to run the build from Xcode."

Comment: Hmm. HAve you tried to remove all gradle-related stuff from your project, and creating new wrapper with executing `gradle wrapper` from CLI.

Comment: Thank you @Artyom Degtyarev! deleting the `.gradle` folder and creating a new wrapper `$ gradle wrapper` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the record here is the solution, **all the credits go to @Artyom Degtyarev**.

1. remove the `.gradle` folder of the project
2. create a new wrapper with the command `gradle wrapper` in your terminal
3. sync your project with the gradle files

Once the synchronization done, the error message is not displayed anymore and the project is executable.

> these operation have been done with Gradle 7.2